# Quarkus - Keycloak client in ServerRequestFilter in reactive context

Tags: java, keycloak, quarkus, vert.x, reactive

I'm using Quarkus with `quarkus-resteasy-reactive` and the `quarkus-keycloak-admin-client-reactive` extensions. I'm building a `ServerRequestFilter` that queries keycloak for a user attribute, but even though I'm using the reactive client, I'm getting `BlockingNotAllowedException` when calling its methods.

Here's the filter:

```
public class Filters {
    @Inject
    Keycloak keycloak;

    @ServerRequestFilter
    public Uni<Response> filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {
        return Uni.createFrom().item(() -> 
                keycloak.realm("my-realm")
                        .users()
                        .search("user-that-i-get-from-context")
                        .stream()
                        .findFirst()
                        .orElseThrow()
                        .firstAttribute("the-attribute")).map(attr -> {
                            if (attr.equals("some-value")){
                                return null;
                            }
                            return Response.status(403).build();
                        });
    }
}
```

I've tried adding `runSubscriptionOn(Infrastructure.getDefaultWorkerPool())` to the `Uni` but the error persists.

Making the requests blocking is not an option, as I want my endpoints to be reactive.

I suspect the problem is somewhere in the context of the filter and in the injection of the `Keycloak` client, but I've been unable to pinpoint the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, KeycloakClient uses classic ResteasyClient blocking and not ResteasyReactiveClient.

I solved it using Vertx like this:

```java
import io.vertx.mutiny.core.Vertx;

public class Filters {

    @Inject Keycloak keycloak;
    @Inject Vertx vertx;

    @ServerRequestFilter
    public Uni<Response> filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {
        return vertx.getOrCreateContext().executeBlocking(
            Uni.createFrom().emitter(emitter -> {
                var attr = keycloak.realm("my-realm")
                        .users()
                        .search("user-that-i-get-from-context")
                        .stream()
                        .findFirst()
                        .orElseThrow()
                        .firstAttribute("the-attribute");

                if ("some-value".equals(attr)) {
                    emitter.complete(null);
                } else {
                    emitter.complete(Response.status(403).build());
                }
            }));
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Jean, this code does not compile, i get 
```
Required type: Handler <Promise<T>>
Provided: Uni <Object>
```

Comment: You should import Vertx from mutiny
`import io.vertx.mutiny.core.Vertx;`

Comment: You're right, I did import from the wrong one (even though I had actually tried something similar before and in that time I imported the correct one)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that although `quarkus-keycloak-admin-client-reactive` used RESTEasy Reactive under the hood and does non-blocking API, the Keycloak API does not expose a Mutiny API variant.
What you are trying to do with Mutiny won't work.

The only solution currently is to make your filter a blocking filter by returning `Response` instead of `Uni<Response>`

Answer (score 0):

@Jean Merelis 's answer works, kudos to him for putting me on the right path. Just want to add that I also found that
that `runSubscriptionOn(Infrastructure.getDefaultWorkerPool())` also works but only if I do the supplier variant of `Uni.createFrom().item()`, otherwise mutiny will consider the item inside to be a completed uni and will not switch the context from the event loop to the executor thread. When I tested it, I was using the non-supplier variant:

```java
Uni.createFrom().item(keycloak.realm("my-realm")...)
                .runSubscriptionOn(Infrastructure.getDefaultWorkerPool())
```

So the code I posted in the question will work with `.runSubscriptionOn(Infrastructure.getDefaultWorkerPool())`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue which I solved as follows using a `Uni.createFrom().completionStage(future)`:

My use-case was getting a Keycloak User resource and representation as part of a Uni pipleine then using that User data to update the Keycloak user further down the pipleine.

The custom `KeycloakUser` class returned below simply stores the resource and representation for later use.

The simplified imperative function that gets a Keycloak User data:

```java
private KeycloakUser doGetKeycloakUser(String username){

  // Get our realm resource
  realmResource = keycloak.realm("quarkus");

  // Get the Users
  UsersResource usersResource = realmResource.users();

  // Get the specific user by username
  List<UserRepresentation> user = usersResource.search(username);

  // Get that User's representation
  UserRepresentation userRepresentation = user.get(0);

  // Get the user resource via the user id
  UserResource userResource = usersResource.get(userRepresentation.getId());

  // To update a Keycloak user we need both the representation and the resource.
  // My KeycloakUser class just stores them for later use downstream in the Uni pipeline.
  KeycloakUser kcUser = new KeycloakUser(userRepresentation, userResource);

  return kcUser;
}
```

Then I call that function as part of my Uni chain like this:

```java
  public Uni<KeycloakUser> getKeycloakUser(String username){

    // FYI: about this block:
    // While it is true you are using the quarkus-keycloak-admin-client-reactive
    // ie a *reactive* client,
    // the org.keycloak.admin.client.Keycloak itself is not reactive.
    // So, when you call it as part of a Uni pipeline,
    // it blocks the IO thread and throws a BlockingNotAllowedException.
    // See: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/29786
    // So, here we wrap the blocking function doGetKeycloakUser() in a CompletableFuture
    // and run it as an async operation, then when it completes we
    // turn that completionStage into a Uni.

    CompletableFuture<KeycloakUser> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
      return doGetKeycloakUser(username);
    });

    return Uni.createFrom().completionStage(future);
  }
```

Maybe not the best solution, but it works.

In your tests, you need to use `awaitItem()` instead of `assertCompleted()`:

```java
Uni<String> uni = adminClient.getKeycloakUser(username)
  .chain(kcUser -> adminClient.setAttributeToUser(kcUser, "mykey", "myvalue"))
  .onItem()
  . ...

UniAssertSubscriber<String> subscriber = uni.subscribe().withSubscriber(UniAssertSubscriber.create());

subscriber.awaitItem().assertItem("Was set");
```